# Should I say “You lack of idea”, “You lack idea”, or “You are lack of idea”?

Tags: word-usage

I searched each of these "you lack of idea", "you lack idea", "you are lack of idea" & they all come out some results so there must be someone is using them.

But, *I do not know which expression is correct!*

or *are they all correct?*

Comment: Souldn't it be ideas? I'd say "You are lacking ideas" or "You lack ideas". But I think you can't say "of idea"

Comment: None of them are correct. _Lack_ is a transitive verb, not an adjective, so (3) is out. And it doesn't take a preposition before its object, so (1) is out. But _idea_ is a count noun and requires either pluralization or an article, so all three are ungrammatical anyway. If the article were corrected in (2), it would be grammatical.

Comment: @JohnLawler I'd vote that answer up.

Comment: so many native English people use it incorrectly right? I found these results on the internet so there must be someone is using them.

Comment: So many people (over 10,000 hits for "you lack of idea") are indeed using it incorrectly. I doubt many of them are native English people though.

Comment: Looking at some of the hits I think these might be common mistranslations.

Comment: The first results page says 10,000+ but when I page through them, there are in fact only 28.

Comment: @TimRomano 10,000. 29. Near enough. In fairness to Google, these few times might be the first times anyone has ever searched for that. I doubt the results were cached.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

None of them are correct. *Lack* can be two things:

### Verb

In its verb form, it is a *transitive* verb. This means that is takes an object, you *lack **something***. Using it as a verb in your examples, you could say:

> - You *lack* an idea.
> - You *lack* ideas.

---

### Noun

As a noun *lack* means *something that you do not have or do not have enough of*. You can have *a lack **of** something*. Rephrasing your examples, you could say:

> - You have *a lack of ideas*.
> - You have *a lack of an idea*.

Note that saying that you **are** a lack does not make any sense. Someone *has* a lack of something. However, something can *be a lack of something*:

> His problem **is** *a lack of confidence*.